# Silverlight DataVisualization Pie Charts

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, charts, windows-phone

I am working on Windows Phone 8 app development.

I am using Silverlight DataVisualization Pie charts.

Is there any way, when the user taps on the Pie chart slice get the value of that slice? and also double tap ?

Here my code:

```
<charting:Chart
                Style="{StaticResource PhoneChartStyle}"
                Template="{StaticResource PhoneChartPortraitTemplate}"
                x:Name="MyPieSeriesChart">
                <!-- Series -->
                <charting:PieSeries
                    ItemsSource="{StaticResource Activities}"
                    DependentValuePath="Count"
                    IndependentValuePath="Activity">
                    <charting:PieSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="charting:LegendItem">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 15 0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Style>
                    </charting:PieSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                </charting:PieSeries>
            </charting:Chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable item selection in pieseries, you need set

```
IsSelectionEnabled="True".
```

To get the slice value

```
 private void PieSeries_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PieSeries p = sender as PieSeries;
        var a = p.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, i have set it, but how will i get the values on click of that slice ?

Comment: I've modificed the answer

Comment: Thanks it worked, is there any way that i can disable the color when i tap on the slice, or suppose if i have red color slice when i tap also  it should be in red color only

Comment: Can you mark it as an answer if it has helepd you, you could modify the slice style using blend.

Comment: Yes i will accept the answer, can you please show me how to modify the slice style , just steps is also enough

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715959/ive-customized-my-toolkit-pie-chart-but-now-all-slices-are-same-color

Comment: Create a style for your clicked events add that to your resource and apply that style On pressed state

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49474/discussion-between-goofy-and-sajeetharan)

Comment: can you please  join the chat room ?